How do I pour a patio cement slab in my backyard next to my home without voiding the warrenty?
I am building a new house and would like to build a patio that extends the length of the house from one end to the other.  My warranty would be voided if I pour the slab and it touches the home foundation. I am thinking about pouring the slab 6" from the home foundation and filling it with small stones.  Would that work?  Any other ideas?

You are building, so the builder should be around to ask this question.  By patio I am imagining a cement slab, so it touching or not should not hurt a concrete foundation.

This really sounds like a question for whoever is providing the "warranty."

This is almost more a legal question as to what exactly constitutes or defines "touching the house"
You could use PE foam expansion joints  between the foundation and poured slab, and not have added any modification to the home.  This again is a matter  of interpretation.
I believe the flavor of the rule is that the builder does not want to be held responsible if the structure itself is modified.  For example if you pour a patio and then add a roof tied into the original roof and then experience a leak.
